# What is the output of this condition in the Prime Function?

Tags: javascript, function, primes

I found this code from another post and I'm trying to understand a part of this solution.

```js
function sumPrimes(n) {
  function isPrime(num) {
    for ( var i = 2; i < num; i++ ) {
        if ( num % i === 0 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
    var arr = 2;
    for ( var i = 3; i <= n; i+=2 ) {
        if ( isPrime(i) ) {
            arr += i;
        }
    }
return arr;
}
console.log(sumPrimes(10));
```

The part I'm asking about is this particular function

```
function isPrime(num) {
        for ( var i = 2; i < num; i++ ) {
            if ( num % i === 0 ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

especially this line in question

```
num % i === 0
```

What I can understand is that `arr` is an array that product every odd number after 2 (for example, [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]). Then every number is run through `function isPrime`. What I'm trying to understand is what are the outputs of `num % i === 0` in relation to `for ( var i = 2; i < num; i++ )`?

Are the outputs like this?

- 3(num) % 2(i)
- 5(num) % 3(i)
- 7(num) % 4(i)
- 9(num) % 5(i)
- 11(num)% 6(i)

Comment: in the `isPrime()` function, only need to check all odds less than the sqrt `for ( var i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(num); i+=2 )`

Comment: Why not just test it? Writing a small loop to test the output would have likely taken less time than writing this question. Do you understand what `%` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
for ( var i = 2; i < num; i++ ) {
    console.log(`${num} % ${i} === ${num % i}`); // Extra line
    if ( num % i === 0 ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In this code, what the code is actually doing is it's going through every single number between `2` and `num`, assigning it to the variable `i`, and checking if `num` is divisible by `i`. If it is, then it'll return `false`.

The `%` function (called the modulo function), basically takes two numbers, and returns the first number's remainder when divided by the second number. So, for example:

```js
5 % 2 // = 1, 5/2 = 2 with 1 left over
7 % 3 // = 1, 7/3 = 2 with 1 left over
```

If the remainder is `0`, then obviously the first number is divisible by the second number, since there's nothing left over. So **the line `num % i === 0` is checking for divisibility**, essentially - it's checking if `num` is divisible by `i`.

For example, when checking `5` (with the extra `console.log` line), this is what's outputted to the console:

```js
5 % 2 === 1
5 % 3 === 2
5 % 4 === 1
```

And this is what's outputted with `6` as `num`:

```js
6 % 2 === 0
```

(It's stopped, because `false` is returned.)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very clear explanation of this code!

Comment: @KristinaBressler No problem! You can try out the sample code I've provided (with the extra line in) if you want to experiment with the code. Using `console.log` can help understand the code, if you're not sure what's happening.

Comment: I will remember this trick that you add in that extra line for next time I need to test a line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator is the modulus operator. It returns the remainder after division. So `n % x` will be zero any time n is evenly divisible by x.  In this example it's testing whether the number is divisible by any of the previous numbers.

The line `num % i === 0` returns true whenever `num` is evenly divisible by `i`

Answer (score 0):

It means that if the rest of division of num by i equal 0 then num is divided by a number other than 1 and itself, then it is not a prime nubmer so return false. ('%' mean modulo or rest of division)

Answer (score 0):

`%` is the modulus operator. `x%y = x mod y =` the remainder when `x` is divided by `y`. So `4%1=0`, `4%3=1`, and `4%4=0`.

Therefore, `x%y==0` is equivalent to "x is divisible by y". Therefore the loop is checking, for each number from `2` to `num - 1`, is `num` divisible by that number. For a prime number, the answer will always be no. So any case where `num` is divisible by `i`, it is definitely not prime. If `num` is not divisible by any number in the range, then it's prime.

Interesting side note: the loop doesn't have to go all the way to `num-1` - it could stop at `sqrt(num)` (rounded), do you see why?