# How to follow steps in Exact Change challenge using While loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am studying this part of the code in order to understand the "Exact Change" FreeCodeCamp problem. The part of the problem asks to return the change in coins and bill. Meaning that if the total change is $1.25, it checks if the cash machine have plenty of change to return, and if yes, it will return the changes in **"$1"** dollar bill and a **"quarter"** coin.

In other words, I will need to check if the total change is higher than the money denomination such as "one hundred" bill, "twenty" bill, "ten" bill, "five" bill, "one" bill, "quarter" coin, and so on... if so, then I will need to subtract the money denominations from the total change and from the cash machine's change denominations.

Here's my code:

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  
  var total = cash - price;
  
  var denom = [{name:"ONE HUNDRED", val:100.00}, {name:"TWENTY", val:20}, {name:"TEN", val:10}, {name:"FIVE", val:5}, {name:"ONE", val:1}, {name:"QUARTER", val:0.25}, {name:"DIME", val:0.1}, {name:"NICKEL", val:0.05}, {name:"PENNY", val:0.01}];
  
  var changeleft = total;
 
 //Reduce method use on the denom array. The "[]" is the first argument of the accum parameter in reduce function method. Next, another parameter, represent each object in denom array. Index iterate through the array.
  var result = denom.reduce(function(accum, next, index) {
   var totalcharge = 0.00;
    
    if(changeleft >= next.val) {//check if total change is higher than the money denomations in denom array
     while(changeleft >= next.val && cid[index][1] >= next.val) {//check if total change is higher and if the money values from cid array is higher
       totalcharge += next.val;//add the money value from denom array to totalcharge
       changeleft -= next.val;//subtract total from total change
       cid[index][1] -= next.val;//subtract total from cash machine's money
      }
      accum.push([next.name, totalcharge]);//push the name and the total to accum array.
      return accum;
    } else { //why is it necessary?
     return accum;
    }
  }, []);
    
}

console.log(checkCashRegister(19.50, 20.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]));
```

There are several things that I don't understand or would like to see. I don't understand why the **else statement** in the reduce method is necessary. I've noticed that without the else statement, it returns an error saying that it cannot read the property "push" of undefined.

The thing that I would like to see is the steps in the console detailing how the reduce method works. For example, I could have used this line: `console.log(`${num} % ${i} === ${num % i}`);` from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383561/what-is-the-output-of-this-condition-in-the-prime-function) in which the best answer explain how one can see the steps in order to understand how it works. So how do I write a line to list the steps in console.log? I tried doing that but it keeps going on without stoping so I had to force close the browser in order to stop the process.

Answer (score 0):

The else is not necessary but it is important to return something else accum for the next iteration would be undefined, the object returned in the first iteration would be used in the next iteration in the variable accum

Comment: So basically, the 1st step would be [ ] + 0.25, 2nd step would be 0.25 + 0.25?

Comment: 2nd step would be [0.25] + 0.25 => [0.25, 0.25]

Comment: Is there any way I can get this code to list out those steps?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to list the steps in console.log

Answer (score 0):

`Array.reduce` iterates over each index of an array and applies the function passed as the first argument. Each iteration uses the value returned from that function (in the previous iteration) as the first argument to that function. The first iteration uses the second argument to the `reduce()` function.

In this example, `accum` is the value returned from each iteration. So, if there is no `else` branch, nothing is returned and therefore `accum` will be undefined in the next iteration.

You can move the `return` statement outside of the `if/else` branch to remove the `else` branch completely.

Here's the code without the `else` statement:

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  const denom = [{name: "ONE HUNDRED", val: 100.00}, {name: "TWENTY", val: 20}, {name: "TEN", val: 10}, {name: "FIVE", val: 5}, {name: "ONE", val: 1}, {name: "QUARTER", val: 0.25}, {name: "DIME", val: 0.1}, {name: "NICKEL", val: 0.05}, {name: "PENNY", val: 0.01}]

  let changeleft = cash - price
  return denom.reduce(function(accum, next, index) {
    let totalcharge = 0.00
    if(changeleft >= next.val) {
      while(changeleft >= next.val && cid[index][1] >= next.val) {
        totalcharge += next.val
        changeleft -= next.val
        cid[index][1] -= next.val
      }
      accum.push([next.name, totalcharge])
    }
    return accum
  }, [])

}

console.log(checkCashRegister(19.50, 20.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]))
```

Comment: If I move the return statement and delete the else branch, I noticed that it returns all the objects in the array. For example, it'll return [["PENNY", 0], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0.50], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0, ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0] when it should return only ["QUARTER", 0.50]